# Download file via Webservice and Push it to Azure Blob Storage via Node/Express

Tags: angularjs, node.js, azure, express

I need to retrieve files from a vendor's Web service and push these into a unique blob container so users have a unique "workspace". Essentially, I would get files down from the vendor and users could edit these via the files in their own blob container so they don't cross each others working files. I have the unique blob containers working, but need to "download"/GET the files from my vendors API and push them into a blob container. I am able to successfully retrieve the files, which will be separate calls to get a PDF, text files, and images... but if I attempt to upload them to Azure Blob Storage, I get the following error in Node.js:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null

I am thinking that I need to encode the files as base64 on the client side to properly get the length, and have seen some examples of using a Canvas with toDataURL, but am unsure if this is the best method for essentially downloading and pushing directly to Azure Blob Storage, especially since I have files such as PDFs (not sure if PDFs can be base64 encoded).

Here is my AngularJS controller that calls the service (note that the actual endpoint may change depending on which files they call, so I am using a client side GET of files to control variables that a user may enter in a form):

```
$scope.getFiles = function () {

$.ajax({
url: 'http://vendorwebservice.net/ws/file1',
type: "GET",
success: function (result) {
console.log(result);
var filename = 'Texture_0.png';

$http.post('/postFile', { filename: filename, file: result }).success(function (data) {
console.log(data);
}, function (err) {
console.log(err);
});

alert("Files Retrieved!");
},
error: function (error) {
console.log("Failed to download image!");
}
})
}
```

Here is my backend/Node/Express code:

```
app.post('/postFile', function (req, res, next) {
    var filename = req.body.filename;
    var file = req.body.file;
    var base64Data;
    fileBuffer = decodeBase64Image(file);
    blobSvc.createBlockBlobFromText('blob5', filename, fileBuffer.data, { 'contentType': fileBuffer.type }, function (error, result, response) {
        if (!error) {
            console.log("Uploaded" + result);
        }
        else {
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
})

// Decode file for upload
function decodeBase64Image(dataString) {
    var matches = dataString.match(/^data:([A-Za-z-+\/]+);base64,(.+)$/),
        response = {};

    if (matches.length !== 3) {
        return new Error('Invalid input string');
    }

    response.type = matches[1];
    response.data = new Buffer(matches[2], 'base64');

    return response;
}
```

**Update 1:**
Per Gary's suggestion I have tried the following, but messed up the code a bit since my vendors API does not have file URIs but rather endpoints that produce a file on a GET (aka, I am lost on how to pass the endpoint in versus Gary's example that makes sense). For example, my vendors endpoint of 'http://vendorapi.net/ws/texture_0' returns a file named "Texture_0.png".

Front end Angular Code:

```
 $scope.getFromVendor = function () {
            var filename = 'Texture_0.png';//jpg,txt...
            $http.post('/uploadapifiles', { filename: filename, url: 'http://vendorapi.net/ws/texture_0' }).success(function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            }, function (err) {
                console.log(err);
            });
        }
```

Server Side Download Processing (I believe this is the one that is the most messed up:

```
app.get(http://vendorapi.net/ws/texture_0', function (req, res, next) {
    res.download('http://vendorapi.net/ws/texture_0' + req.params.filename);
})
```

Server Side Upload Processing:

```
app.post('/uploadapifiles', function (req, res, next) {

    var filename = req.body.filename;
    var r = request(req.body.url).pipe(fs.createWriteStream('http://vendorapi.net/ws/texture_0' + filename))
    r.on('close', function () {
        blobsrv.createBlockBlobFromLocalFile('blob5', filename, 'http://vendorapi.net/ws/texture_0' + filename, function (error, result, response) {
            if (!error) {
                console.log("Uploaded" + result);
            }
            else {
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
    })
});
```

Comment: Actually, the data we get by using `toDataURL` from a image is in base64 encode type which should begin with `data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADIA...`. And test and PDF files are different, so directly using `decodeBase64Image` may get something wrong. So we should handle in separate depending different file type. And is that available to you to provide the URL of getting files, as I can't make sure of what will get from the URL.

Comment: I can't post the API, but I can log it out if that helps.

Comment: Trying my code with an image generates the same error

Comment: But in this scenario, the way you upload image data is different with the scenario you posted yesterday. So are there 2 separately scenarios?

Comment: Yes they are. Yesterday is uploading from a Canvas, while this need is uploading a file I "Get" from a vendors API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your original idea, at first you get file content data in client side and then post the data to the Express web server.

If the file you get is in a large size, it will slow down your site because of the file data will be transferred twice via HTTP, and it may occur other problem.

Furthermore, in my test project, it is hardly  to handle with file content data directly.

So I tried another idea as a workaround.

I just post the API of getting specific file to the server, pull the file save as a file on server directory and upload file to Storage on server side.
Here is my code snippet:

Angular front end:

```
$scope.upload =function(){
    var filename = (new Date()).getTime()+'.pdf';//jpg,txt...
    $http.post('http://localhost:1337/uploadfile', { filename: filename, url: 'http://localhost:1337/output/123.pdf'}).success(function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    },function(err){
        console.log(err);
    });
  }
```

Back end:

I suspect the API which you get the file form would be like behind.

```
router.get('/output/:filename', function (req, res, next) {
    res.download('upload/'+req.params.filename);
})
```

The post request handler leverages package [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request), and there is no necessary to figure out file type or encoding type, `createBlockBlobFromLocalFile` will upload the file at the location you provide on blob storage, [API reference](http://azure.github.io/azure-storage-node/#toc6):

```
router.post('/uploadfile', function (req, res, next) {
    var request = require('request');
    var filename = req.body.filename;
    var tmpFolder = 'upload/', //this folder is to save files download from vendor URL, and should be created in the root directory previously. 
        tmpFileSavedLocation = tmpFolder + filename; //this is the location of download files, e.g. 'upload/Texture_0.png'
    var r = request(req.body.url).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(tmpFileSavedLocation))//this syntax will download file from the URL and save in the location asyns
   r.on('close', function (){
        blobsrv.createBlockBlobFromLocalFile('vsdeploy', filename, tmpFileSavedLocation, function (error, result, response) {
            if (!error) {
                console.log("Uploaded" + result);
           }
            else {
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
    })

})
```

Comment: This approach makes a lot of sense. One challenge I have is that the web service API provided by my vendor does not give a URI, but rather an endpoint that then downloads the file (ex. calling 'http://vendorwebservice.net/ws/file1' downloads myfile.pdf).

Comment: The first part of the back end code snippet also provides a API to download a file. E.g, browsing `http://localhost:1337/output/123.pdf` in the browser in my project, it will download the file but show the content of file on browser. So you can have a try first, if you have any further concern, we can discuss later.

Comment: Thanks Gary, I had tried that earlier. My updated code is in my original post. This generates an error of throw "er; // Unhandled stream error in pipe.". Because my endpoint is not a URI, but rather a URL without a true file at the end, I believe I messed up the code rather poorly/got a bit lost.

Comment: Also, is upload/ supposed to call another Express function?

Comment: OK, I see.There are some misunderstanding of you. First, the Download Processing is not necessary in your issue, as it is for me to simulating your vendor URL. Second, `var r = request(req.body.url).pipe(fs.createWriteStream('upload/'+filename)` this syntax will download the file to the server and save the file in folder named 'upload'. I will modify my answer to explain it in code.

Comment: This is starting to make sense. One confusion point, if my API is http://vendorapi.net/texture how do I incorporate that as you have output/filename and I don't have this call.

Comment: you have confused in `output/filename`. the `output/filename` in  createWriteStream() is a file path to save files download from vendor url. see the [API reference](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createwritestream_path_options). And I have edited my answer, I modified the code snippet and added some comments. igore `router.get('/output/:filename', function (req, res, next) {
    res.download('upload/'+req.params.filename);
})` please

Comment: Ah! This makes perfect sense now. I was too hung up on the output/:filename. It works perfectly!!! But just as important is the learning I have taken away from this. I cannot underscore how much I appreciate your time and efforts to explain, not just answer a need.